# R: How to knit pdf and only printing output but suppress messages without `suppressMessages`?

Tags: r, knitr

```
---
title: 'title'
author: "author"
output: pdf_document
---
```

Consider this function:

```
doSomething <- function() {
  message("a message")
  2
}
```

And if I put that inside an R Markdown document:

```
doSomething ()
```

Then the output in the PDF will contain both the "a message" and the value 2 once knitted from RStudio. How do I suppress the "a message" without using the `suppressMessage` function?

Comment: Add the chunk option `message=FALSE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
```{r, message=FALSE}
doSomething ()
```
````

See https://yihui.org/knitr/options/ for more info.